# Why Background Service stops working when app is closed?

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to create a background service that will be called every ten minutes, perform a task and this should not be killed when the application is closed.

The following is the code snippet:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_service);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverLifeLog.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

In `onCreate`, it will call the `AlarmReceiverLifeLog` class every ten minutes. The following is the code for `AlarmReceiverLifeLog` class:

```
public class AlarmReceiverLifeLog extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent ll24Service = new Intent(context, LifeLogService.class);
        context.startService(ll24Service);
    }
}

public class LifeLogService extends Service {


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
        PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + 100, restartServicePI);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out what I have missed. When I close the app the background services is getting killed.

Can anyone suggest anything regarding this?

Comment: you need to extend intentservice which creates a separate thread to perform your task,  then the service will persist

Answer (score 0):

when the app is closed the service get closed also because they are in a one thread, so the service should be on another thread in order fot it not to be closed, look into that and look into keeping the service alive with alarm manager here an example http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html this way your service won't be shown in notification.